# What's the benefit of using extend.js?

Tags: javascript, dependency-management

I just got acquainted with [*extend.js*](https://github.com/searls/extend.js), and was wondering if there's an added value to using the library over using native JavaScript. Let me demonstrate;

With *extend.js*, I would declare a namespace like so:

```js
extend('some.madeup.namespace',{
   foo : 'bar'
});
```

… whereas without it, I'd only have to do that:

```js
var some = { madeup : { namespace : { foo : 'bar' } } };
```

I'm a firm believer in the KISS principle, and I really think external dependencies should be reduced to make things a little bit simpler. So, if all this library does is save me the (one-time) assignment declaration, I ponder if it's worth the trouble.

Is there anything I'm missing here, is this all there's to it?

Comment: I'm all for KISS too. That's why I don't use jQuery, for instance. Or any other framework. If I write all my code myself, I can actually have a clue where to start debugging it.

Comment: var some= { madeup: { namespace: { foo: 'bar' }}}; // more compact

Comment: @SteveH. - you're just making me angrier, as the question is more relevant :) i'll edit my question accordingly, just to emphasize the issue. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect a sensible answer to this question leans heavily on a generic answer for any third party tool.

People use third party tools when it helps them get the job done faster and more elegantly, at least that's the theory. But there are people, myself included who find it more elegant to reduce dependencies and to implement from scratch. To us there is little value in including sugar in our projects, because this devalues our principles.

To others it has values because it reduces the amount of code they have to write and perhaps feels slightly more structured. They would have made the same abstraction themselves, so it makes sense to use a well thought out and tested library.

It weights heavily on your personal preferences and usage. Admittedly I have not addressed the usage of this library in particular, it is only 51 lines of code. It shouldn't take long to read over the features it's providing and to come to your own conclusions.

From what I can tell this library merely creates namespace hierarchies and checks for conflicting namespaces. Most of the code seems to be focused of creating the hierarchy and verifying namespace distinctness. This would suggest to me it's been designed as a general purpose tool in situations where conflicts might occur - say you are publishing your own library for mass consuption.

If you want my opinion though, it would be from a person who wouldn't use it by choice. Namespaces are actually unnecessary. All that effort to prevent multiple namespace conflicts on window does sound necessary if you are actually concerned about conflicting namespaces, but any good design never would be.

Comment: this is all clear to me, and obviously 'it shouldn't take long to ... come to conclusions', but i was hoping for a practical response from someone who used this library in a project (on a large scale, maybe) and had asserted the pros and cons thoroughly. thanks anyhow for your response.

Comment: Hopefully you can find something meaningful in the final comments. As I tried to highlight, it's a very subjective problem. If you were to detail the sepcifics of the use case you are considering to solve with this library then someone might be able to offer better advice on it's use. I certainly doubt that anyone using it would have experieced issues with it. You highlighted yourself that you don't see the point. I guess what you need is to find someone who suffered from multiple namespace conflicts. I don't because I choose good design, and this simply fixes bad design in my opinion.

Comment: interesting edit, how would you define a 'good design'? why are namespaces unnecessary?

Comment: This library fixes the problem of multiple libraries **registering themselves** in global scope. In my opinion global scope never needs to be touched, and third party modules certainly shouldn't register themselves. I much prefer the module.exports and require sort of syntax you find in NodeJS, so modules are safely loaded from within your own closure. This seems like a much better way of avoiding global conflicts. People do find namespaces acceptable, particularly as that's how things seem to be done on the client, I just personally think module loading is better.

Comment: well, that calls for a whole other question, you've contributed a-lot, but i challenge you to post your thoughts on the subject [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054125/why-are-namespaces-considered-bad-practice). thanks a lot for all your efforts.

Comment: Since the question was closed I will just add a quick note here. In gerenal people seem to find namespaces accpetable, because that's what they are used to using. In JavaScript we can avoid using namespaces, and they are considered bad (by some) from the perspective that globals are bad (and a mistake in the design of JS if you listen to Crockford), but this certainly isn't the popular opinion. But at any rate, namespaces are supposed to be carefully chosen names. This is why you find the reverse domain name notation in Java, because it's linked to something that is supposed to be unique.

Comment: If you have to worry about namespace collisions, there is something wrong with your design. I do happen to use the "namespace" technique occasionally, just because it is simple and people I work with understand it. What I would never do it use a third party library to manage namespaces and namespace collisions, because if I thought that were a possibility in my use case then I am doing it completely wrong.

Comment: Interesting thread, I just stumbled upon it. I wrote extend.js for the sole purpose of making it easy to work with (potentially deep) namespaces in JS apps. Because I typically work with a bunch of tiny files in development, this function is very helpful for reducing parse-time load order dependency by defining each layer of the namespace on demand. In practice it's served me and a couple other teams well over the years; not sure what else is worth saying that isn't in the README. :-)

Comment: Try looking at the CommonJS approach with Browserify. You typically have to deal with many small modules in CommonJS, it's just the way, but we don't use global namespaces. We derive local tokens using require. I find deeply nested namespaces pretty unnecessary anyway, but I guess it depends on what you are doing.