# Why are namespaces considered bad practice in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I've been told namespaces shouldn't be used, as they 'pollute' the global scope. I wonder what are the alternatives?

When I want to define utility functions and / or constants e.g. for a website, a simple way to go would be to define them by namespaces, that way the damage to the global scope is restricted to one object only.

If namespaces are bad practice, a couple of questions comes to mind:

1. Why is this bad practice?
2. What's the scope of this declaration (web applications / dynamic websites / static websites etc.)?
3. What are the alternatives?

*<sub>This question is a result of a discussion started on [a post on the benefits of using extend.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049616/whats-the-benefit-in-using-extend-js).</sub>*

Comment: And I always thought that namespaces are exactly for *not* polluting the global scope... (`->` they are **good**).

Comment: Yeah, someone has this backwards.

Comment: @FelixKling namespaces still pollute the global scope. You don't need global tokens in JavaScript, ever. Anyone who uses them is doing it wrong.

Comment: @Raynos: Of course each top-level namespace creates a symbol in global scope... but how would you access an external library if it wouldn't?

Comment: @FelixKling custom module loaders using closures. Libraries shouldn't expose global tokens, they should expose their modules using a standard format like AMD or commonJS and module loaders should extract these modules out and handle inter module dependencies. This can be done with zero user-created global tokens (even avoiding temporary global tokens)

Comment: @Raynos: And how do you access the module loader? You need *some* global symbol. I'm not talking about that the user should create global symbols.

Comment: Those hippie namespacers! Call the Global Variable Police!

Comment: @FelixKling you don't need global symbols. The module loader is an independent file that that wraps itself in a closure then loads your entry file for you, then recursively loads dependencies. An example of how to avoid having a global `define` token for AMD is loading modules as text and then `eval`íng them in the closure scope where the `define` token is defined.

Comment: @Eliran - In summation of the heated rhetoric flying around here, less is better than a lot (namespace variables approach), but there are techniques to eliminate global variables such as you suggested. It comes down to how you approach it and what you are comfortable with in your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why is this bad practice?

namespaces themself are bad because it's an unnecessary concept.

Having objects with properties and methods is acceptable. It's also fine to have a "module" token which is similar to a "namespace" but instead the meaning is that you have one "module" token per file which contains all your properties and methods. This is different from a "namespace" because it's only created / altered in a single file and isn't exposed as a global token.

> what's the scope of this declaration (web applications / dynamic websites / static websites etc.)?

All ECMAScript, never create new global tokens

> what are the alternatives?

Rather then having namespaces you should favour multiple "file local" tokens. Meaning that each file / "module" should be wrapped in a closure and you should have access to multiple local variables inside this closure.

Global variables are also bad because you don't need them, at all, ever. The way you avoid globals is by wrapping everything in closures and being intelligent in how you load external javascript files.

Examples of zero global module loaders

- [node-browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)
- [webmake](https://github.com/medikoo/modules-webmake)
- [modul8](https://github.com/clux/modul8)

Further reading:

- [Modularity without globals](http://clux.github.com/modul8/docs/modularity.html)
- [CommonJS modules](http://clux.github.com/modul8/docs/xcjs.html)

Comment: There are only two globals needed: the AMD `define` and `require` functions. ;)

Comment: There are zero globals needed. You can inject the tokens `define` and `require` into modules by means other then global tokens

Comment: Sorry, but you've lost me here. If I'm using an AMD-compliant loader and I want to define a module, I do `define(...)` - so `define` has to be there for me to use as a global, no? (Of course not defined by me, but by the AMD loader.) And the same is true for actually loading and executing code that uses modules, there I need `require`.

Comment: Raynos, I know you're skilled enough to have a point, but what you're lacking is actual example code demonstrating what you're talking about (see bullet 3 in the question).

Comment: @JaredFarrish [node-browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) zero globals.

Comment: Ok, is somebody supposed to dig through that and find the code that makes your point? The first think I [clicked on](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/master/index.js) shows five global variables.

Comment: @JaredFarrish all these files are wrapped in closures for you. Wrapping each individual file in a closure is ugly when a build task can do it for you. Those are "file local" tokens or "module scoped tokens"

Comment: @Lucero the `require` token is passed in as a function argument to the `define` function. The `define` token is wrapped in a closure and you can only access it because the module loader runs your code through `eval` rather then by including files directly through `<script>`. Think of it as `<script data-main='entry.js' src='require.js' />`. It does require jumping through a few hoops in the module loader library.

Comment: I see your point. However, it makes loading libraries in a specific order (which unfortunately is sometimes needed in the real world) or using things such as polyfills difficult to say the least. If I can directly use `define` and `require` in my script tags, I'll have more control for dealing with these. That said, I agree that general code ought not to declare any globals (and I do, in fact, clear out globals set by libraries such as jQuery after loading them in order to avoid code falling back to some globals by mistake).

Comment: You're confusing namespaces with global objects or global namespace (neither are inherently a bad thing). Namespaces are very much a necessary concept. Without it, you can't have separate scopes (if all your local scopes shared a single symbol table, then that's really just one big global scope). You're right that most people's use of globals (myself included, unfortunately) can and should be avoided. However, having global objects like `window` and the standard objects in EMCAScript and DOM _is_ necessary, as those are _global_ objects that need to be shared amongst all your code.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté `> never create new global tokens` There is nothing wrong with touching or using existing global tokens. There is also nothing wrong with a global symbol table that enforces / protects against namespace collisions but there is no need for this namespace concept.

Comment: if I have my entire library here - `(function () { // my library here}());`, I have exposed 0 globals.  Is this statement correct?

Answer (score 3):

I can't imagine why a namespace would be a bad thing. Unless there's some definition of namespace that is specific to JavaScript that I'm not aware of.

I'm currently working on a small library, and everything is enclosed by one top-level object (namespace?). I don't put anything on the window or intrinsic types; if you need something from my library, it's available in the `kilo` object.

To me, having this 'namespace' is a **good** practice as it lets me know very quickly if I'm calling a method in my library. There's no need to override the `window.alert` method which might screw with another library loaded on the page; just use `kilo.alert` for the customized version (this is a contrived example, but I hope it makes the point).

Comment: You don't need a 'namespace' to know whether your calling a method from a library, you just manipulate the objects and tokens exposed by that library.

Comment: I guess what we need is a clearer definition of namespace. JavaScript doesn't have them, but we're talking about them like it's actually part of the language. Really, I just use a parent object for my library. A namespace isn't really a thing in JavaScript; even what is being called a namespace here is really just a chain of objects.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think people who say you should *never* pollute the global scope fail to properly define "polluting". You can see this to some extent in the native `Math` object, for example. Every other programming language I know has all the math functions as just plain functions, but JS doesn't. However, if you were to take this to an extreme, a simple alert box would be `core.dialog.alert` instead, for instance.

I like to enclose all of my code in closures, to keep the variables clean. However, my main JS script file defines a bunch of utility functions *in the global scope*, such as a custom `Alert()`, or `AJAX()`, or other widely-used functions. If I'm going to use them often, I don't want to have to bloat the file with namespace calls. And since I define all my variables in closures there's no risk of accidentally overwriting the functions (I might do so in the closure itself, but it had no impact on the global scope).

Overall, namespaces are overrated. Just write your code already and don't cry over every single `window` property.

Comment: Your recommending people to use global variables, this is a bad practice.

Comment: Namespacing and other techniques are much more useful in certain environments where you may have layered libraries that could conflict. For instance, JIRA uses namespaces to place things like jQuery outside of the window scope, but there's a significant number of libraries it uses, so it makes sense. Overall, nobody yet has made the point of *why* you should avoid global variables in JS, which is that they are so easily overwritten by any other script and you may have problems if that happens. So it makes sense to be careful, without getting overblown about it in general.

Comment: The other issue with globals is that they are global, anything can read / modify / corrupt / alter / generally mess with them. This is similar to the concept that you shouldn't embed SQL queries directly in views in your server-side web applications. Basically globals break seperation of concerns

Answer (score 0):

"namespaces" in JavaScript are really just objects with named properties.  In other OO languages (i.e. C++, C#, etc), I don't think you would want the following:

C# --

```
public static class MyAppName {}
public static class MyArea {}
public static class MySubArea {}

public static class Test {
  public string Property1 { get { return "test"; }}
}
```

Just so you can have

```
MyAppName.MyArea.MySubArea.Test.Property1;
```

So basically, because JS doesn't actually support namespaces, people have invented a hack to simulate namespaces which then makes it 'cool' to write stuff like:

```
myAppSpace.mySubArea.myObject = blah...
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea (not to mention bad form) to reference "the real world" and then include code from some other language to make your point.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I believe he's trying to illustrate that this "namespace" concept when ported to another language like C# also generates ugly and silly code.

Comment: @Raynos - I know what the point is supposed to be, we're talking about JS. And that's C#.