# Better way than Window.Object?

Tags: jquery, object, global-variables

Is there a better way for jquery to store a global variable?

```
window.activedepth = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
alert(window.activedepth);
//other functions that use activedepth
})
```

im just curious. I need to store the activated menu depth.
http://jsfiddle.net/dichterDichter/dX34n/2/embedded/result/

**EDIT:**
works great now without global Vars, thx to: adeneo
http://jsfiddle.net/dichterDichter/R3tsp/

Comment: Use the module/iife pattern (or even jq-load or similar) and create all the functions within that scope. It might be possible to avoid "global variables" entirely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it bad practice declaring global variables in a.js file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579355/is-it-bad-practice-declaring-global-variables-in-a-js-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. jQuery has an internal `$.data` object where you can store data, created so you can store data on an per element basis without needing global variables.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).data('activeDepth', 0);

});
```

or

```
jQuery.data( document.body, 'activeDepth', 0 );
```

[**jQuery.data**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

[**$(element).data()**](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: So i cound even store the Data to the #menu Div?

Comment: @dichterDichter - Yes, you can store arbitrary data on any element without needing globals, that's what's great about jQuery's data()

Comment: Awsome. Just tried it. in my script i used this but somehow i didnt think about storing this var to the menu div. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Outside the function the variable declaration is global. So,

```
var activedepth = 0; //global variable

$(document).ready(function() {
alert(activedepth);
//other functions that use activedepth
})
```

Do the same as you have.

Comment: didnt work somehow. this was my first step but i got an "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to avoid "global variables" entirely, simply use a lexical variable in the scope around all the functions that use said variable:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var activedepth;
    // Other functions and usage of said variable here here..
})
```

This doesn't work across `<script>` elements or inline event handlers, however.

Comment: yes, i tried that before. my script worked somehow but when i wanted to check for activedepth it gave me "undefined"

Comment: @dichterDichter Then you've either assigned the value undefined or, more likely, you've not assigned a value yet. (Or are accidentally referring to a different variable.)